# How the quotas of google drive sdk works?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am starting to develop a windows-like client google drive client for linux.

I have some problems that I am solving yet, but one no technical question are worrying me.

The drive sdk has request limit, I want open my app like other options (for example gdrive ) but the request limit will avoid general availability.

I need put a personal id, but I suppose that is not the way to publish the app.

How other options solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the limit on google-drive api usage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311969/what-is-the-limit-on-google-drive-api-usage)

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive Apps have a "courtesy limit" of 10 million requests per day I believe.

I cannot imagine a situation in the near future where you will run into issues.

If so this is often referred to in the world of software development as "the good problem".

Google will no doubt allow you to scale if your app provides value to users and needs the bandwidth.