# Google Drive API quotas when access using Google Play services?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I understand we have Drive API quotas  [when we use web apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311969/what-is-the-limit-on-google-drive-api-usage)

is there any quota if we use Android Google Play Services Drive API?

How do i increase this?

Background:

My app uses google drive to sync app data between devices, so as soon as user initialize a device he will setup another device, for sync to happen immediately I use requestSync.

```
 Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(gClient).await(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Frequently i get sync issues due to requestSync failure with error

`Sync request rate limit exceeded`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Drive API allows a free quota of 10,000,000 requests/day. However, this figure only represents the per day Quota available to a developer. You could be hitting rate limit errors because you are hitting the requests/second number which is by default 10.

To change the Requests/User/Second rate, you need to log into your Developer Console and change the number. However, [implementing Exponential Back-off](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors#implementing_exponential_backoff) algorithm will be much more advisable than setting your App's per second quota limit to a higher number. From Developer's console, you can also request additional quota in case you have Exponential Back-off algorithm in place to handle your rate limit errors and are hitting the quota limits per day.

For information on why quota limits are in place, please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311969/what-is-the-limit-on-google-drive-api-usage).

Comment: The quota for Drive API queries is completely separate from the rate limit on DriveClient.requestSync.  The requestSync rate limit is still a completely undocumented limit, with much speculation about whether it is enforced at the device or account level.  Developers are consistently experiencing inconsistent results when using that function.

Comment: Correct, but not entirely.One, you are referring to a post written in 2015, in 2018. Things have changed quite a bit since then. For example, the DriveAPI interface is now completely deprecated(in 2019).

Comment: Two, Rate-limits pertaining to requestSync specifically might not be published, but that should be covered in the Quota. If not, that's a problem to be communicated with them by raising a bug, and not taking your disappointment on a community member trying to help another one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the time difference.  I agree that it's pointless and harmful to downvote old answers such as this one due to changes in accuracy, and tried to remove my vote.  Unfortunately, it says that the votes are locked in unless the answer is edited.  Maybe the answer can be deleted for being obsolete, so it no longer negatively affects your reputation unnecessarily.