# How to upload multiple files upload in google drive?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have gone through the documentation provided on https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads but i'm unable to found a way to upload multiple files by single api request. I have used multipart and resumable both but they need single file(source). But i want to select multiple images(in thousand) to upload with resumeable operation.

Please help me or guide me a better solution in any technology.

Many Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot upload multiple files with only one request. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039152/best-strategy-to-upload-multiple-files-to-google-drive-via-javascript-api) What you could do, is to append your array/list with your items(images) and then foreach this array/list and send the item as a parameter to your method/function.

Comment: Can I ask you about the maximum file size in the files that you want to upload to Google Drive?

Comment: @Tanaike max file size is not fixed.

Comment: @GoodNickName i want to upload images in huge amount as per your suggestion if i hit api for each image then i will cross request quota limit.

Comment: You need to upload each file separately. You can request more quota from Google if necessary.

Comment: @pinoyyid thanks. What is default quote and how much i can request to google team. My requirement is to upload millions of images in day. I don't want user to upload zip or directory.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/limits

Answer (score 0):

create a bundle from mutible files use 7z or winrar zip then upload it as a single file extract it later on drive