# Google Drive Rest API Limitations

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to use the Google Drive Rest API for my Application as a CDN. Are there any bandwith or traffic limitations?Lets say 100.000 users want to download the same file (200MB). Is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Drive API comes with a free quota as follows:

Queries per day 1,000,000,000
Queries per 100 seconds per user    1,000
Queries per 100 seconds 10,000

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/quotas

These limits can be increased on application.

There may also be other limits as outlined in this post
[What is the limit on Google Drive API usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311969/what-is-the-limit-on-google-drive-api-usage)

Comment: Ok so 100.000 downloads are not a problem?

Comment: @B3nni I would suggest trying with some test code to see how many queries are likely per file download in your specific case. Also see second link  added to the post as there may be other limitations on using Drive as a CDN