# Where can i see more api quotas price?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

We are planning to release our app soon. There are limits to API quotas if our application gets popular then our API may increase so where can I see price details for more API quotas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the limit on Google Drive API usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311969/what-is-the-limit-on-google-drive-api-usage)

Comment: @DaImTo where can I see the price if want to increase more quotas?

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive is a free API. There is no documented pricing for it.

I have seen Google require payment for quota extension in the YouTube api and Maps apis I have never heard of anyone being charged for access to google drive.

This is probably because any agreement for a quota that high would probably be confidential between the company and Google.  Or there just isnt any pricing for Google drive api.

Comment: is there any official page or doc stating that would bring a lot of peace in mind.

Comment: See funny thing is normally Companies only document things that you should be aware of.  There is no documentation on pricing because there is not pricing because its a free API.   If there was pricing there would be documentation on pricing.   see the correlation?  