# Google Drive API 1 billion queries per day limitation

Tags: wordpress, google-api, google-drive-api

I am managing a Wordpress website that uses the Ultimate Video Player plugin in order to render video files that are stored in my Google Drive account.

Plugin details: https://www.webdesign-flash.ro/p/uvp/

In order to render the Google Drive video files, this plugin needs the video file sources to be created using the following format:

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[file_id]?alt=media&key=[api_key]&v=[.mp4/.mp3/etc] (which is actually the download link for the specific file)

Therefore I have created a Google API key that I’m using to build my video source links.

In the Quotas section, I see that there is a limitation of 1 billion queries per day.

Does this mean that my video files can be played by my website’s users 1 billion times without exceeding the limit? Does watching an entire video (one full movie) just decrease this 1 billion limitation by 1? Or does the download quota decrease in a different way when it comes to watching videos?

Thank you!

Comment: It's been a while since I used any Google API, but I think you can check in your dev console somewhere how many times an API has been accessed. So perhaps you can just test? Download a few video files from your drive and see how many queries each download was counted as.

Comment: Thank you Azer for your reply. Unfortunately the console numbers are not updated in real time and that's why I'm having trouble figuring out exactly how it works. Anyway, I have dropped this solution because it doesn't meet my needs.

Comment: Hi ! I believe your question might be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311969/) . Does [this answer solve your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10313416/12835757)? It seems that every API request (i.e someone downloading the file) will be counted as 1 use. Please, let me know if you believe your question is a duplicate or if that answer solves your issue :D

Comment: Hi Mateo, yes that thread does answer my question. Thank you so much your reply!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the limit on Google Drive API usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311969/what-is-the-limit-on-google-drive-api-usage)