# Google Drive Api - Error after copying multiple files .NET - Cancel connection by remote host

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Console application below return exception after copying many files. I'd like to know the exactly limit of copying and creating folders with Google drive api in .NET. Follow the Inner Exception: "Unable to read data from the transport connection: Was Forced to cancel the exist connection by remote host".

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
        string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly, DriveService.Scope.DriveFile };            
        ServiceAccountCredential credential;                                    
        using (var stream =
                        new FileStream("key.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {                            
            credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                                 .CreateScoped(Scopes)
                                 .UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;                
        }
        // Create Drive API service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Test App",
        });            
        Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File copiedFile = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {                
            copiedFile.Name = "";                
            copiedFile.Parents = new List<string> { "1I6eCYECR8lfpWP6wFDWeYkTsUMC6jKie" };                 
            try
            {
                var lFile = service.Files.Copy(copiedFile, "157cV64pH6Jdpm8SER1MQStPhnl01XHI65AsfPwSeTqw").Execute();
                Console.WriteLine("File " + (i+1).ToString() + " copied.");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {                    
                Console.WriteLine("Error = " + e.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }                     
    }
```

[Print_Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5Ear.jpg)

Comment: Have you try to remake the request? Maybe you are making too many request and that is reaising some flags. Another option that would probably solve your problem is inserting a little [`sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=netcore-3.1) function. You could try that and comeback.

Comment: @Raserhin Thanks for answering! I've tried with "sleep" and the error remain. I think remake the request be something to think about. My concerns about is always remaking unecessary requests and spend resources and quota.

Comment: How many miliseconds between every request? Does this always happen in the same file number? You could try a retry of the request when this specific error comes out?

Comment: @Raserhin I have set the sleep to 1000 but the error remain. I realized that when I was testing my web app creating folders and files (different files) randomly. I'm sure if you run my console app on your side you will see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for helping! I've realized that our SonicWall firewall was blocking some requests. After set (Sonicwall) to not block our request, the issue was resolved.
    I have attached the full error here.

[Print Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmVDk.jpg)