# Google drive API developer key and webContentLink expire time

Tags: php, web, google-drive-api, storage, google-developers-console

I thought to store my photography website's photos on google drive and fetch the images using google drive API with PHP. I have more than 1 million photos in my website. So I want to get to know whether it's feasible enough to make it with google drive API? Does google has API request limit or do they change the webContentLinks time to time? Would it be a good idea to store all my photos on google drive ? I hope to purchase 2TB space from google. Any idea?

Comment: You have got this wrong. You don't need to recommend anything. I just want to get to know the feasibility of doing this with google. I have seen many questions here in stackoverflow asking questions like my self :)

Comment: Check out this answer about Drive API quotas, which are per counted per GCP project. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10313416/4243927

Comment: Did you get further with this?

Comment: Yes, API developer key doesn't expire. But webcontent links expire day by day I think. So we cant store in a database for future use. We will have to use the API and fetch the links when we need them.

Comment: Where adid you find the information about the webcontent link limits?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10313416/4243927) about Drive API quotas, which are per counted per GCP project.